# ld can't find right version of libx11

Tags: compiler-errors, ld

I'm building htk (http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/) from source but I'm having troubles compiling. This is the output of make all:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so when searching for -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a when searching for -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
```

I think it's because that version of the library is x64 but I installed the 32-bit version  by running:

```
# apt-get install libx11-6:i386
```

but apparently the compiler is not able to find it, neither am I.

Comment: Why did you install the i386 version? If you really need that, you should install `libx11-dev:i386`, too.

Comment: Because apparently everything was set up to compile on 32 bit systems, but you're right, I forgot to install the dev package, it's working now!